# Aligning div elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating n number of div elements dynamically using a for loop. I wanted those div elements to be aligned this way as shown below.

If even number of div's get generated:

[1][2]

[3][4]

[5][6]

if odd number of divs are generated:

[1][2]

[3][4]

[5]

How can I accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your DIVs have for example `class="x"`, you can float them and use this CSS:

```
.x {
  float: left;
}
.x:nth-child(odd) {
  clear: left;
}
```

(This only works if your DIVs are narrow enough to fit into the width in pairs)

```css
.x {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 160px;
  background: #cae;
  margin: 3px;
}

.x:nth-child(odd) {
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="x"></div>
<div class="x"></div>
<div class="x"></div>
<div class="x"></div>
<div class="x"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using flexbox. You can view a cheat sheet here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ though the gist is that you make a container with display: flexbox (and change the width to what you like), then as long as your child elements have width: 50% (or a bit less than 50% if you plan on having margins/borders), the layout will achieve what you want.

I believe it's also good practice to limit how often you change the DOM. For example if you know you're going from 0 to 5 divs, then you should use the for loop to create the HTML string for all 5 components then set the parent container's innerHTML in one call, rather appending 5 times.